# SQL: Is GETDATE() a deterministic function or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

SFMC Limitation: We can't use variables
Self Limitation: No usage of SSJS

I use SQL Query Activity to get the previous day's records from Midnight to Midnight, just like a Tracking Extract might.

e.g.

```
WHERE
  u.EventDate BETWEEN DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), 00, 00, 00, 000 )
  AND DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), 23, 59, 59, 997 )
```

What I am trying to understand is; is the `GETDATE()` function deterministic, e.g. evaluated once per the `SELECT` statement or it non deterministic, e.g. evaluated each time it is called?

Is there any other way of doing this as well where I don't need to repeat `DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [sargable](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/55535/sargable-queries-in-sql-server-with-examples/) method that I typically use to get yesterday's records:

```sql
select
o.subscriberkey
from _open o
where
o.eventdate >= convert(date, getDate()-1)
and o.eventdate < convert(date, getDate())
and o.isunique = 1
```

Converting to `date` effectively resets time portion to midnight and using a range captures all times between midnights.

Appears `getDate()` is [non-deterministic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: If it is sql server 2005 or older it will be deterministic, if it's newer then it is non-deterministic. I couldn't find anywhere which version we were using. This helps simplify tho, thanks.

Comment: It’s SQL Server 2016, so non-deterministic as shared by Adam